# C# Avoid Repetitive code and use Generic

Tags: c#, generics

The subject might look like that this question is already been posted, but my code snippet and problem is different.
Please have a look at it.
I have some 20 to 22 Sql tables of which I have created my POCO class in my Application. Each of these tables have some 4-5 common columns to which I need to fill some records in the application,rest columns of the table are already filled by XML data sent by some other application. The only 4-5 common columns of each table I am trying to fill in the application as below.

```
private List<Software> GetSoftwareEntityData(Information request, DateTime scanDateTime)
{
    List<Software> Data = new List<Software>();
    int SrNo = 0;
    foreach (var item in request.Software)
    {
        Software d = new Software();
        d = item;
        d.DCDTime = DateTime.Now;
        d.LastModDTime = scanDateTime;
        d.ID = request.Id;
        d.ScanDateTime = scanDateTime;
        d.SrNo = ++SrNo;
        Data.Add(d);
    }
    return Data;
}

private List<Users> GetUsersEntityData(Information request, DateTime scanDateTime)
{
    List<Users> Data = new List<Users>();
    int SrNo = 0;
    foreach (var item in request.Users)
    {
        Users d = new Users();
        d = item;
        d.DCDTime = DateTime.Now;
        d.LastModDTime = scanDateTime;
        d.ID = request.Id;
        d.ScanDateTime = scanDateTime;
        d.SrNo = ++SrNo;
        Data.Add(d);
    }
    return Data;
}
```

Similarly I have written code for 22 tables each and these functions are being called when I am dealing with that specific set of object.

How can I create a Generic method, so that I can get rid of 22 functions which have repetitive code?

I am posting my Information class also here below.

```
public class Information
{
 public List<Software> Software{get;set;}
 public List<Users> Users{get;set;}
}
```

So now my Software and Users class looks like below with an interface implementation called ICommonColumns.

```
public interface ICommonColumns
{
DateTime DCDTime{get;set;}
DateTime LastModDTime{get;set}
.....
and others common fields
}

public class Software : ICommonColumns
{
....
}

public class Users : ICommonColumns
{
....
}
```

Comment: You can genericize all but the `foreach (var item in request.Software)` line pretty easily.  You could have a generic function handle everything but that line, or you could probably do that bit with Reflection, but I am not sure how that would be done.

Comment: I think in your case the best approach would be to extract those fields into a different table, at least that's what I would do, but if you are working with legacy tables and you can't change the logic there have a look at this link, it shows how to implement a generic repository: http://www.tugberkugurlu.com/archive/generic-repository-pattern-entity-framework-asp-net-mvc-and-unit-testing-triangle

Comment: So foreach (var item in request.Software) looks a challenge for me. How would I generalize that?

Comment: The foreach mackes it difficult. I'd question the benfit of using generics here. You'll save *some* code but increase the complexity. Personally I'd live with the duplication I think

Comment: Can you explain what this does? `Users d = new Users(); d = item;` in your example? Creating a new `Users` and overwriting that object, doesn't make sense..

Comment: Hi @Spluf, yes the problem is I can not change any implementation of the legacy tables, what ever I can do I have to deal with the application.

Comment: Sure @JeroenvanLangen, So `code` Information request `code` is a collection of User, Softwares and so on which are already filled by the XML data except few common fields which I am trying to fill in the with the methods.

Comment: @praveen.upadhyay What kind of properties do you need of the `Information request`? I can't see any. You're only reading an `item` and assigning _(overwrite)_ it to the newly created object.

Comment: @JeroenvanLangen As I said in my previous comment, Information request has a collection of all data like Software, Users etc, So Information object already has filled up these information except the common which I am trying to fill in.

Comment: @praveen.upadhyay As I said in my previous comment, what kind of information/properties would you like to access within the loop (of an item of Information.Users. Because i don't see any... The code you provided doesn't compile probably...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both `Software` and `Users` will need to have a constraint to ensure that they have *something in common*, such as an `interface` or base class.

```
public class BaseEntity
{
    public DateTime DCDTime { get; set; }
    public DateTime LastModDTime { get; set; }
    public DateTime ScanDateTime { get; set; }
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int SrNo { get; set; }
}
```

For example, your `Software` class would look like this:

```
public class Software : BaseEntity
{
    //Some more properties
}
```

Then you can create a generic method like this:

```
private IEnumerable<TEntity> GetEntityData<TEntity>(int requestId, IEnumerable<TEntity> requestEntities, DateTime scanDateTime)
    where TEntity : BaseEntity, new()
{
    int SrNo = 0;

    foreach (var item in requestEntities)
    {
        TEntity d = new TEntity();
        d = item;
        d.DCDTime = DateTime.Now;
        d.LastModDTime = scanDateTime;
        d.ID = requestId;
        d.ScanDateTime = scanDateTime;
        d.SrNo = ++SrNo;

        yield return item;
    }
}
```

And call it like this:

```
IEnumerable<Software> softwares = GetEntityData<Software>(request.Id, request.Software, DateTime.Now);
IEnumerable<Users> users = GetEntityData<Users>(request.Id, request.Users, DateTime.Now);
```

Comment: I think the `requestEntities` type and the returned types aren't the same or doesn't share a base class type.

Comment: Yes they are not same

Comment: In the software method you have, you are instantiating a new `Software`, then doing this: `d = item;`. This looks like they are the same type?

Comment: `where TEntity : BaseEntity` ensures that any type arguments passed in **must** inherit from `BaseEntity`, this allows you to access the properties, such as `DCDTime` and `ID` for example. `new()` isn't actually required here, so I'll remove it.

Comment: @MikeEason how would I iterate through requestEntities and return a new set of IEnumerable<TEntity>. If you can see that in my code, I have something like this.

Comment: In that case, you would in fact need the `new()` constraint. I have updated my answer.

Comment: Thank you @MikeEason. I have updated my question and added Information class how it looks like. could you re- look at it. With you solution I am trying a bit different. I am using an Interface instead of BaseEntity. I am getting error when calling the Generic method

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114239/discussion-between-praveen-upadhyay-and-mike-eason).

Answer (score 3):

Why not have the POCO's implement an interface and create a method that accepts implementations of that interface?

Edit:

```
public interface ISomething
{
    public DateTime DCDTime { get; set; }
    public DateTime LastModDTime { get; set; }
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public DateTime ScanDateTime { get; set; }
    public int SrNo { get; set; }
}
    private IEnumerable<T> GetSoftwareEntityData<T>(Information request, DateTime scanDateTime, Func<Information, T> someCollection)
    where T : ISomething
   {
    int SrNo = 0;

    foreach (var item in someCollection(request))
    {
        item.DCDTime = DateTime.Now;
        item.LastModDTime = scanDateTime;
        item.ID = request.Id;
        item.ScanDateTime = scanDateTime;
        item.SrNo = ++SrNo;

        yield return item;
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks great. Could you please post a sample over my example with a Generic example too.